# how to switch to timestamp parse in Flink SQL Client

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I want my `Flink SQL Client` to read data from Kafka
and the data produced by kafka is `Timestamp`style,
but the default Flink SQL Client Parse is `DateTime`style,

How to force Flink SQL to switch to `Timestamp`style?

Thanks for  your help~!

[image]

my .yaml file is   [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XFWMsDWM9y/)

Answer (score 2):

I think, the transformation are looking for is`TO_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(<your column>)` e.g. like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE your table (
  unix_ts STRING, --your original column
  ts AS TO_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_ts))
) WITH (
  ...
)
```

Some more examples for time/data handling can be found e.g. in https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/master/recipes/12/12_date_time.md.